# Filtrar list string con otra lista String que tenga conincidencia - JAVA

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, filtro, stream

Se tiene una lista de string y se desea filtrar los string que contengan alguna coincidencia con una lista personañizada, la lista es:

```
["EMAIL:test@mail.com", "Shipper: ", 
 "Address :Ground Floor Bench Road", 
 "STAR LIMITED", "MOON INC", 
 "PHONE: 555-555"
]
```

y se desea filtrar si se encuentra alguna de estas palabras:

```
["STAR", "address", "contact"]
```

El resultado esperado es:

```
["EMAIL:test@mail.com","Shipper: ", "MOON INC", "PHONE: 555-555"]
```

He intentado de varias formas y no lo he logrado obtener

```
// Custom List
List<String> filterWordsList = Stream.of("STAR","Address", "contact")
                                     .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

// data
List<String> dataList = Stream.of("EMAIL:test@mail.com","Shipper: ", "Address :Ground Floor Bench Road", "STAR LIMITED", "MOON INC", "PHONE: 555-555")
                              .map(String::toLowerCase)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());


// Test No. 1
List<String> filterData= dataList .stream()
                    .filter(line ->!new HashSet<>(filterWordsList).contains(line.toLowerCase()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Test No. 2 
List<String> filterData= dataList .stream()
                    .filter(el -> Arrays.stream(filterWords)
                    .filter(word -> word.toLowerCase().contains(el.toLowerCase())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Test No. 3 
List<String> filterData= dataList .stream()
                    .filter(word -> filterWordsList.stream()
                    .anyMatch(w-> w.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema en cuestión?

Comment: @padaleiana El proposito es filtrar una lista con otra lista de palabras, para dejar las palabras que no tengan coincidencias con el listado de palabras

Comment: Esa es la finalidad. ¿Qué problemas obtuviste en tus intentos? ¿Qué resultados estás obteniendo que son distintos a los esperados?

Comment: Los resultados no son los esperados, cuando pasa por el filtro la lista resultante sigue siendo la misma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente, tienes que filtrar el contenido de una lista contra el contenido de otra, lo que tradicionalmente se trabajaría con un `for` dentro de otro `for`. Usando la API de Stream, algo así se genera con:

```java
List<String> filterWordsList = Stream.of("STAR","Address", "contact")
                                     .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Sin toLowerCase para obtener el resultado deseado
List<String> dataList = Arrays.asList("EMAIL:test@mail.com", 
                                      "Shipper: ", 
                                      "Address :Ground Floor Bench Road", 
                                      "STAR LIMITED", 
                                      "MOON INC", 
                                      "PHONE: 555-555");

List<String> result = 
        dataList.stream()
                .filter(data -> // El filtro que pides es excluyente, asi que va negando
                     filterWordsList.stream()
                                    .noneMatch(fw -> data.toLowerCase().contains(fw)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Que tras un `System.out.println(result.toString());` resulta en

```
[EMAIL:test@mail.com, Shipper: , MOON INC, PHONE: 555-555]
```

Comment: 's mil y mil gracias, ya logre ver donde estaba fallando y es la forma como estaba comparando, pero con tu ayuda lo pude observar.